# Can GO be used as a scripting engine within an application?

Tags: windows, scripting, go

Can *GO* be used as a scripting language within an application ? I can't find any informations about this: is there a dynamic link library version which could be interfaced from a Windows application with some standard methods such as *Compile()*, *Execute* and features such as *callbacks*, *variables sharing* etc ?

Comment: See also some suggestions here: http://www.reddit.com/r/golang/comments/qjyhp/a_difficult_decision_switching_from_go_to_java/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This might sound strange at first but go with me on this: I think it would be a perfect candidate for a scripting language because it's compile time is so fast....hear me out...

Most scripting languages are interpreted, and so they do not require (or even provide in some cases) compilation. However compiled languages are safer in general because they can catch certain errors at compile time, which is better than, for example, catching a syntax error at runtime.

With Go, the compile time is so speedy that whatever program is running your Go code (e.g. a web server) could hypothetically compile the code on-demand if the code has changed, and otherwise use the compiled version.

Actually if you check out Google App Engine and download their dev web server for Go (https://developers.google.com/appengine/) you'll notice that their web server does exactly this. If you run through their Hello World tutorial for Go you'll notice that if you make changes to your code you won't need to recompile the Go code in order for the changes to take affect.

Comment: It looks strange because I should initially ask "Is Go can be used as LUA".

Comment: I don't think there are necessarily any tools available yet for it to be used the same way Lua is, since it's such a new language. But it seems to be growing pretty dang fast so my guess is that those tools will be available soon. For now you might be able to rig something with the help of some C libraries. I don't think anything exists yet though.

Answer (score 5):

[Go](http://golang.org/ref/spec) is not a scripting language. Because Go is designed for fast compilation, there have been some attempts to use it as a scripting language. For example,

- [gorun](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/gorun)
- [GoNow](https://github.com/kless/GoNow)

Comment: That's different. Those are a way to simply run a go program as if it were a script. The OP wants to know about using Go as a scripting engine within a larger application, e.g. how Lua is commonly used.

Answer (score 0):

In theory (and perhaps somewhere out there w/o me knowing), Go can be used as a script language. Just note that it makes as much sense as using e.g. C as a scripting language.

Comment: ok but Google doesn't provide a kind of VM embedded in a dll or something ?

Comment: No, it doesn't. This is a compiled language.

Comment: But I'd say it's probably more doable than with C, as GO offers more API (like reflect) for the access of exposed internal structures, functions, etc. I'm sure some guys are doing it already (and I'm sure I won't want to use that).

Comment: Actually if it's compiled it doesn't exclude the integration into an application , after all arent dll mapped into the process memory at the runtime ?

Answer (score 0):

No. Go code cannot be used within a non-Go application unless Go is responsible for starting up the whole app.

Comment: That's the way the current implementation works.  The Go authors are certainly entertaining other ideas for the future though.  See for example, https://groups.google.com/d/msg/golang-nuts/7DoIQePXnpo/R-2LU4n4rxcJ